# unistd write() stops writing after 100 consecutive socket write/reads, program returns 3328 error code

Tags: c, sockets, http, unistd.h

I am trying to test the amount of traffic my website can handle, and so I created a C program to send a bunch of consecutive requests to my website (probably not the best way, but I did it just because I don't really know C, not because I *really* need to test load-handling). Here is the relevant code (if you really feel like you need the full source, see [here](https://github.com/MuhammadYojer/simple-load-tester)):

```
while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        write(socket_id, request, strlen(request));
        read(socket_id, message, 1024 * 1024);
}
```

where `socket_id` is the id of an established socket connection, `request` is the HTTP request to be sent, and `message` where the results of the `read` will be stored. This is the HTTP GET request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
From: ...
```

I am tracking views on via a php script in my website.

No matter how long the thread `sleep`s, it still crashes after 100 write/reads. Why is this?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)?

Comment: What are the values returned by `write` and `read`, in case of failure, what is the `errno` value? (Hint: use `perror()` function)

Comment: @jeff6times7 HTTP 1.1 (what I'm using) is persistent by default. Are you suggesting using or not using persistence?

Comment: @purplepsycho The return values of `read` and `write` are never `-1`, so that is not the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadYojer It depends on whether or not you expect most of your web site's client requests keep a connection open. If they do, then the way you're testing is appropriate. If you're not sure, then you should test both ways. Be that as it may, you may get closer to answering your own question if you stop using persistent connections.

Comment: Unrelated: `#endif //CONNECTOR_H_INCLUDED` should be on the *last* line of `connector.h`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is bad because you never test the return values of read and write and so you could still try to access the socket after it has been closed server side, but that should not cause a crash.

But after looking at your github code, I noticed that you *define* `struct sockaddr_in servaddr;` in a .h file that is included in 2 different c files. It is true that some compilers can allow it, but it is not conformant C because it does not respect the One Definition Rule. In fact, you define twice the same variable in one single program causing Undefined Behaviour.

The correct way is to *declare* the variable as external in the include file: `extern struct sockaddr_in servaddr;`, and only *define* it in one single c file. In you current source, you could even only declare it in the connector.c file.

But in general global variables are a nightmare because they could be changed at a unexpected time from an unexpected place, and result in using a wrong value. At least `servaddr` should be declared static in connector.c.

Comment: I checked the return values, and they're always valid (never `-1`). In addition, I moved `servaddr` from `connector.h` to `connector.c`, and declared it static, but that changed nothing; `write` still stops sending after 100 read/write requests. You can see the updated source [here](https://github.com/MuhammadYojer/simple-load-tester).

Comment: @MuhammadYojer: No you do not check the return values of **all** read and writes but only every second, and reading from a socket closed by the peer will return 0. Why dont't you use the common `cr = read(...); if (cr <= 0) {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

Server may close a connection, so you have to test return codes from write and read functions,and if there is a failure, reestablish a connection.

Comment: The return values are always valid (never `-1`), so that is not the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadYojer: What about `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `read`/`write` should be tested, and connection should be reestablished on error:

In file `main.c`, instead of

```
//set up the connection
socket_id = get_socket();
get_ip_address("example.com");
establish_connection(socket_id);
/*...*/
//send the request
while(1) {
    if(write(socket_id, request, strlen(request)) == -1 || read(socket_id, message, 1024 * 1024) == -1) {
        establish_connection(socket_id);
        write(socket_id, request, strlen(request));
        read(socket_id, message, 1024 * 1024);
    }else {
        write(socket_id, request, strlen(request));
        read(socket_id, message, 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

You should write something like:

```
/* query should be declared before this point */
while (1)
{
    /* set up the connection */
    socket_id = get_socket();
    get_ip_address("example.com");
    establish_connection(socket_id);

    /* send the request */
    while (1)
    {
        if (write(socket_id, request, strlen(request))<=0)
        {
            /* something goes wrong while writing, exit the inner while loop */
            perror("write");
            break;
        }
        if (read(socket_id, message, 1024 * 1024)<=0)
        {
            /* something goes wrong while reading, exit the inner while loop */
            perror("read");
            break;
        }
    }
    /* if this point is reach, that means that one write or read call goes wrong */
    close(socket_id);
}
```